# Initial ElasticSearch Bulk Index/Insert /Upload is really slow, How do I increase the speed?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, elasticsearch, activerecord, bulkinsert

I'm trying to upload about 7 million documents to ES 6.3 and I've been running into and issue where the bulk upload slows to a crawl at about 1 million docs (I have no documents previous to this in the index).

I have a 3 node ES setup with 16GB with 8GB JVM settings, 1 index, 5 shards.
I have turned off refresh ("-1"), set replica to 0, increased the index buffer size to 30%.

On my upload side I have 22 threads running 150 docs per request of bulk insert. This is just a basic ruby script using Postgresql, ActiveRecord, Net/HTTP (For the network call), and and using the ES Bulk API (No gem).

For all of my nodes and upload machines the CPU, Memory, SSD Disk IO is low.

I've been able to get about 30k-40k inserts per/minute, but that seems really slow to me since others have been able to do 2k-3k per/sec. My documents do have nested json, but they don't seem to be very large to me (Is there way to check a single size doc or average?).

I would like to be able to bulk upload these documents in less than 12 - 24hrs and seems like ES should handle that, but once I get to 1 million it seems like it slows to a crawl.

I'm pretty new to ES so any help would be appreciated. I know this seems like question that has already been asked, but I've tried just about everything that I could find and wonder why my upload speed is a factor slower.

I've also checked the logs and only saw some errors about mapping field couldn't change, but nothing about memory over or anything like that.

ES 6.3 is great, but I'm also finding that the API has changed a bunch to 6 and settings that people were using are no longer supported.

I think I found a bottleneck at the active connections to my original database and increased that connection pool which helped, but still slows to a crawl at about 1 Million records, but got to 2 Million over about 8hrs of running.

---

I also tried an experiment on a big machine, that is used to run the upload job, running 80 threads at 1000 document uploads each. I did some calculations and found out that my documents are about 7-10k per document so doing uploads of 7-10MBs each bulk index. This got to the document count faster to 1M, but once you get there everything slows to a crawl. The machines stats are still really low. I do see output of the threads about every 5 mins or so on the logs for the job, about the same time I see the ES count change.

The ES machines still have low CPU, Memory. The IO is around 3.85MBs and the Network Bandwidth was at 55MBs and drops to about 20MBs.

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure if I should try the ES gem, and use the bulk insert which maybe keeps a connection open, or try something totally different to insert.

Comment: I forgot to mention that besides the index changes the ES install is from the apt-get es repo. I haven't really done any custom changes, except the required steps to put ES in production mode (Running through the ES website checklist).

Comment: What database are the original documents in?

Comment: The documents are originally in Postgresql. I've started profiling that DB and noticed that once you use offset of about 1 Million the queries are starting to take a long time. I have multiple indexes, but I'm guessing I need one this specific query, or upgrade the DB hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ES 6.3 is great, but I'm also finding that the API has changed a bunch to 6 and settings that people were using are no longer supported.

Could you give an example for a breaking change between 6.0 and 6.3 that is a problem for you? We're really trying to avoid those and I can't really recall anything from the top of my head.

> I've started profiling that DB and noticed that once you use offset of about 1 Million the queries are starting to take a long time.

Deep pagination is terrible performance wise. There is the great blog post [no-offset](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), which explains

- why it's bad: To get the result 1,000 to 1,010 you sort the first 1,010 records, throw away 1,000, and then send 10. The deeper the pagination the more expensive it will be
- how to avoid it: Make a unique order of your entries (for example by ID or combine date and ID, but something that is absolute) and add a condition on where to start. For example order by ID, fetch the first 10 entries, and keep the ID of the 10th entry for the next iteration. In that one order by the ID again, but with the condition that the ID must be greater than the last one in your previous run, and fetch the next 10 entries plus remember the last ID again. Repeat until done.

Generally, with your setup you really shouldn't have a problem inserting more than 1 million records. I'd look into the part that is fetching the data first.

Comment: Xeraa: Pulling the data from Postgresql using LIMIT and OFFSET was the issue. I ran a limit and offset query at about 2 million rows, even after vacuum and adding in another index and removing 2 indices, and the query took forever (5 minutes or so).

I ran the same query with the > operator and FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY and it took about 300 ms.

Basically my upload script has been waiting for Postgresql to finish the SELECT queries on the large table when using LIMIT and OFFSET. I'm going to recode the script to use the NO-OFFSET way to walk through the records for the initial upload.

Comment: So when doing a lot of googling and finding other peoples setup most of everything that came up was setting your performance settings similar to [https://gist.github.com/reyjrar/4364063]. I'm guessing this is ElasticSearch 5.x and below, but it was hard to find the same settings in 6.x and noticed that they moved from the yml file to an API.

Comment: Great that it's working. I'd just be careful with copying configs — often they cause more harm than good, because they are for a specific setup (workload, hardware,...) / were an improvement with an older Elasticsearch version but are now the opposite / ... Start with the defaults and then work on settings where necessary; though bulk, refresh, and replica were definitely good settings for your scenario.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't trying to copy other's configs, but get a good reference to what was a good strategy to optimize for uploads then set it back to optimize for searching. Once you dive into the ES documentation I realized most of that stuff was there. It was good to see other's configs though to see if what I was doing was the correct strategy. Hopefully this post helps others also.